# anychart - Create a map chart with pie charts

Tags: anychart, anychart-8.2

Using anychart, Is it possible to create map chart and place on top of it pie charts (instead of bubbles)?

For example, I need to show:

France
number of males - 1212
number of females - 2312
Italy
number of males - 964
number of females - 981
So, I would like to see a map of the world and on top of France, I would like to see a pie (prefer the size to be relative to male+female in France) that shows red and green slices that represents the number of females/males  ... and same on top of Italy.

Thx,
Yohay

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the current version of the library (v 8.9.0) doesn't support this possibility.
But we can suggest a few solutions.

Option 1.
You can place the France map inside a donut chart and update the donut chart data by the click on the map bubbles. Like in [the sample](https://playground.anychart.com/vwprOgCn).

Option 2.
You can place a pie chart simply next to the map.

Option 3.
You can show the pie chart in the custom HTML tooltip when the user hovers the map bubble. Like in [the sample](https://playground.anychart.com/8ShdUxBz/2).